# Как сортировать список по спискам внутри?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Список: `[[43,25,18,76],[45,12,8,-15],[67,23,56,98],[12,34,67,-36],[11,46,72,82],[34,76,13,0]]`

Нужно отсортировать этот список по четвертому элементу в каждом списке внутри

То есть результат должен быть:

```
[[67,23,56,98],[11,46,72,82],[43,25,18,76],[34,76,13,0],[45,12,8,-15],[12,34,67,-36]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
l = [[43,25,18,76],[45,12,8,-15],[67,23,56,98],[12,34,67,-36],[11,46,72,82],[34,76,13,0]]

print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[3], reverse=True))
```

Или так:

```
import operator

l = [[43,25,18,76],[45,12,8,-15],[67,23,56,98],[12,34,67,-36],[11,46,72,82],[34,76,13,0]]

print(sorted(l, key=operator.itemgetter(3), reverse=True))
```